# Should there be different starting points for the C times() function in 32- and 64-bit processes?

Tags: c, linux, suse

The following refers to SuSE 11.4 Linux.

When my multi-process software starts on a server, the returned value of the C *times()* function is saved as an integer in shared memory.  (This is OK, because we’re pre-C11.)  Later, calls to *times()* are made to get the starting and ending times for tasks.  For example, a start time is computed as the amount of time since the original call to *times()*, and an end time is computed the same way.  Later, the difference can be taken between the starting and ending time, to compute a task’s duration.

Previously, we only used 32-bit processes.  For the next release, we’re planning on having both 32- and 64-bit processes running on the same server.  However, there seems to be clashing results from *times()*.

According to the documentation, *times()* returns the duration since an arbitrary point in the past.  What I’m finding is that the initial point in the past differs depending on if the process was built as a 32- or 64-bit executable.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>

clock_t getTimes()
{
    clock_t c = times(0);
    int64_t c_int64_t = (int64_t)c & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
    printf("c_int64_t is [%" PRId64 "]\n", c_int64_t);
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(clock_t) is [%d]\n", sizeof(clock_t));

    clock_t c1 = getTimes();
    printf("sleeping for 2 seconds...\n");
    sleep(2);
    clock_t c2 = getTimes();

    double elapsedTime = ((double) (c2 - c1)) / (double)sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
    printf("elapsedTime is [%f]\n", elapsedTime);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it as follows:

```
$ gcc -m32 -oa.32.out clock.c
$ gcc –m64 -oa.64.out clock.c
```

Note what happens when I run it 4 times:

```
$ for i in a.32.out a.64.out a.32.out a.64.out
> do
> echo " "
> ./${i}
> done

sizeof(clock_t) is [4]
c_int64_t is [2286152112]
sleeping for 2 seconds...
c_int64_t is [2286152312]
elapsedTime is [2.000000]

sizeof(clock_t) is [8]
c_int64_t is [2286295196]
sleeping for 2 seconds...
c_int64_t is [2286295396]
elapsedTime is [2.000000]

sizeof(clock_t) is [4]
c_int64_t is [2286152512]
sleeping for 2 seconds...
c_int64_t is [2286152712]
elapsedTime is [2.000000]

sizeof(clock_t) is [8]
c_int64_t is [2286295597]
sleeping for 2 seconds...
c_int64_t is [2286295797]
elapsedTime is [2.000000]
```

As I hope is clear from the results, the 32-bit and 64-bit processes are each consistent amongst themselves.  But they differ between each other by about 142,885 units (or 1429 seconds).  The result of this is that my software can’t share a “base time” between 64- and 32-bit processes.

**Is this behaviour of *times()* normal and expected?**

Comment: Any reason you're not using `clock_gettime`?

Comment: I suppose mainly because the code has been this way for years, if not decades.  But I will take a close look at `clock_gettime` as a possible fix.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, but I don't have SuSE handy and I don't even know which version of SuSE you're using. With Ubuntu 18.04, and having fixed the warnings produced by your code (for example, by adding `#include <sys/times.h>`, which might make a difference), I get consistent results but they're quite different from either of the values you show.

Comment: It's SuSE 11.4.  I updated the question to reflect that.